# Mapping a Oracle Sequence in a Loopbackjs Model

Tags: node.js, oracle, loopbackjs

I have a table in Oracle DBMS which primary key is incremented by a Oracle sequence. This table is used by some applications in my company.

I want build a API using the framework Loopback.io (Node.js). How could I config the models in this new Loopback API the name of this sequence?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the following solution:

I've created an OracleSequence.js file in the server directory that executes a native query for the next value of my sequence:

```js
class OracleSequence{

 constructor(name) {
  this._sequenceName = name;
 }
 
 nextVal(dataSource,cb){
  let valor = -1;
  dataSource.connector.execute(`SELECT ${this._sequenceName}.nextval FROM dual`,null,function(error,resultado){
   if(error){
    console.log(error);
    throw Error(`Fail to execute sequence ${this._sequenceName}`); 
   }
   cb(resultado[0].NEXTVAL);
  });

 }
}

module.exports = OracleSequence
```

Then I've called it in my model hook:

```js
const OracleSequence = require("../../server/OracleSequence");
module.exports = function(Valadares) {

            Valadares.observe('before save',function setaID(ctx,next){
                if(ctx.isNewInstance){
                        let sequence = new OracleSequence("SQ_VALADARES");
                        sequence.nextVal(ctx.Model.app.dataSources['oracleDS'],function(id){
                        ctx.instance.idGV = id;
                        next();
                    });
                } else{
                        next();
                }
        }); 
};
```